# how to use of ping command with mobile agents

Tags: java

i want to make a code in which when a mobile agent moves to the next server it first ping the server if response is "OK" then it move to the next server.
     `

Comment: could you please show some code , what you have tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

```
package in.techdive.java;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.InetAddress;
  import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    public class PingApp
   {
public static void main(String[] args)
{


    String ipAddress = "localhost";

    try
    {
        InetAddress inetadd = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
        System.out.println("Sending Ping Request to " + ipAddress);

        boolean ipstatus = inetadd.isReachable(10000); 
        if (ipstatus)
        {
            System.out.println("Status : Host is reachable");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Status : Host is not reachable");
        }
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Host does not exists");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error");
    }
      }
   }
```

using this you can make ping to url and get the status . hope this will be help to you if you want more help inform me

Comment: i want to know that this run in aglet

Comment: this is the java code .cz you are tagged it under java so i answered never tried with aglet or other platform

Comment: i used java based platform aglet